# replace goto using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, goto

I have a simple digit root calculation (ie. sum all the digits in an integer, and if the total is more than one digit, repeat the process until you end up with a single digit answer).

My first impulse is to simply calculate the sum of the digits in the initial string, test if the result is more than one digit, and if so, goto the start of the summing suite:

eg.

```
line = "123456789"
sum_digits = 0    
# label: if I could use goto, it would go to here!
n_chars = len(line)
while n_chars > 0:
    sum_digits = sum_digits + int(line[0])
    line = line[1:]
    n_chars -= 1
line = str(sum_digits)
if len(line) < 2: # all done
    print("digital root is ", sum_digits);
else:
    goto label: # need to repeat until get single digit root number
```

But, of course, python doesn't support 'goto' -- so I guess this should be written as a recursive function? What is the neatest way to code this?

ps. I'm trying to keep the code very simple to understand/explain as I'm doing this as a coding exercise with my son, who is learning programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the `goto` the idea is to keep track of what the line is after every iteration you find its sum.

So, if I understand your question, the following should work:

```
def find_root(line):
    while len(line) > 1:
         sum_digits = 0
         for num in list(line):
             sum_digits += int(num)
         line = str(sum_digits)
    print line


>>find_root("123456789")
9
>>find_root("93856")
4
```

Comment: I like this answer, as it is easy to explain how it works to my son.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just ["do it the math way"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root#Congruence_formula)

```
def find_root(s):
    return (int(s) - 1) % 9 + 1
```

---

```
>>> find_root("12345")
6
>>> find_root("8753")
5
>>> find_root("6743")
2
```

Comment: but the digital root of "123456789" should come up as "9" and not "0"

Comment: @user2147243, you are right. This can be done by subtracting 1 before the modulo and adding it after.

Comment: But then it fails for `0`.

Answer (score 0):

try a main loop

EDIT: sorry about that, forgot to reset sum_digit

```
line = "123456789"
sum_digits = 0    
# label: if I could use goto, it would go to here!

while len(line) > 1:
   n_chars = len(line)
   while n_chars > 0:
       sum_digits = sum_digits + int(line[0])
       line = line[1:]
       n_chars -= 1
   line = str(sum_digits)
   sum_digits = 0

print("digital root is ", sum_digits);
```

Comment: although this iterates after the first sum comes up with "45", it doesn't come up with the correct answer ("9") as the sum_digits value isn't reset before iterating, so you just keep adding more digits to a two-digit number and next satisfy the exit condition (ie. endless loop)?

Comment: This results in an infinite loop. It's setting line equal to the string casted sum and then repeating the loop because `line` is always greater than length 1.

Comment: sorry bout the inf loop, didnt run the code for real the first time :3

Answer (score 0):

```
def dig_root(line):
    while len(line) > 1:
        total = 0
        for num in line:
            total += int (num)
        line = str(total)
    print "The digital root is: " + str (line)
```

>>> dig_root("12345")

The digital root is: 6

>>> dig_root("8753")

The digital root is: 5

>>> dig_root("6743")

The digital root is: 2

There we go. I need to read more carefully.

Comment: Misses doing it again if the sum >10

Comment: neat coding, but doesn't iterate when end up with more than single digit answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't read it carefully enough. I edited it to be correct, unless you wanted to use the remainder of what's past 9, but that wouldn't be too hard to change.

Comment: "8753" > "23" > "5" should be the answer.

Comment: There it is...Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
def calc_root(num_string):
    root = 10
    num_string2 = str(num_string)
    while root >= 10:
       root = sum([int(x) for x in num_string2])
       num_string2 = str(root)
    return root
```

That will reduce to a single-digit root with no recursion. The idea is that it will stay on the while loop as long as the calculated root is equal or larger than 10.

You could add a check for isdigit on num_string2 and an exception, but that would complicate the code and should be a later step.

Comment: By the way, this uses two concepts of python:
1) A string is a list of characters
2) List comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion and list comprehension:

```
def sumdigits(n):
    if len(n) > 1:
        t=sum([int(d) for d in n])
        return sumdigits(str(t))
    else:
        return n

print sumdigits("123456789")
```

1. get the numbers as string
2. if length of string is more than one recursively call the function to calculate the sum
3. otherwise return the sum

Comment: very nice. now I just have to work out how to explain it to a 13 yo. I may have to expand the "t=sum([int(d) for d in n])" line into something a bit more obvious, then show this as the final, more compact version. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest the following:

```
>>> def digiroot(number_string):
...     while len(number_string) > 1:
...             sum = 0
...             for i in number_string:
...                     sum += int(i)
...             number_string = str(sum)
...     print number_string
... 
>>> digiroot("124")
7
>>> digiroot("12487")
4
>>> digiroot("12487123")
1
>>> digiroot("123456789")
9
```

Comment: I didn't even realize that Nima's answer was up. My mistake, it's practically identical X_x